# How can I download complete website based on login

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download website : https://hkpropel.humankinetics.com/mylibrary.htm. I'm trying to use selenium for login and then use pywebcopy but it return error like :Can't find the file to open in browser. Here is my code

```
path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://hkpropel.humankinetics.com/mylibrary.htm')

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_username"]')
username.send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_password"]')
password.send_keys('password')
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit"]').click()

save_website(
url= driver.current_url,
project_folder="./",
project_name="my_site",
bypass_robots=True,
debug=True,
open_in_browser=True,
delay=None,
threaded=False,
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I find it important to point out that web scraping itself and its usage is highly sensitive and it is recommended that you follow license requirements.

Having said that, we can move on to the task at hand with caution. A website is usually made up of several components and some can be "generated" at runtime according to workflows and policies.

The error you reported here can be found in the original code as a path reference problem. The thing is, this path is [cached](https://github.com/rajatomar788/pywebcopy/blob/701698e82c1f10a567dcd6ef1f413d5438df5018/pywebcopy/elements.py#L188) so there may be a problem somewhere in there.

https://github.com/rajatomar788/pywebcopy/blob/701698e82c1f10a567dcd6ef1f413d5438df5018/pywebcopy/core.py#L230